# swift - set storyboard inside a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to develop a `TableViewController` that shows commands. Every cell of the table is a `collectionView`, but I'm wondering if I can programmatically instantiate a storyboard and pass the initial controller (`collectionViewController`) to that `collectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell`
   [this a schema of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMblI.png).

The question is: Can I put a storyboard inside a `tableViewCell` so I can navigate inside that cell and do stuff ?

**solution**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let st = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let vc = st.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController

    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0,width: cell.contentView.frame.size.width, height: 40);
    cell.contentView.addSubview((vc.view)!)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    return cell
}
```

with `Storyboard` is a custom storyboard with navigationController as its first controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open `ViewController` inside any `UIView` , if you want to `instantiateViewController` `UITableCell`  that open in its `contentView`

```
let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
 self.addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, self.container.frame.size.height);
    cell.contentView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: thanks, this worked fine with some changes to the syntax, I added a button to the `vc` so when I click on it it should navigate to a new controller, It did but it presented the new controller in the main view not in the tableCell

Comment: just push the ViewController using NavigationController Don't persent

Comment: `navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)` that will work , Please make sure your controller is connected to navigationController in StoryBoard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929592/how-to-push-and-present-to-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-without-segue-in-io
visit this for pushing view , i  hope this will help you.

Comment: yes it worked when I embed a navigation controller as first controller in my custom storyboard