# Swift. How to avoid repetition of pushViewController()?

Tags: swift, dry, pushviewcontroller

In my code I have many `pushViewController()` (with `instantiateViewController()` and other stuff) methods in one ViewController. I am just thinking how I can avoid repeating on this chunk of code and make it more clear and dry.

I have found protocol solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43124539/6866265

It looks nice but I would like to see other options.
Thanks

Comment: you can just do an extension of UIViewController maybe?

Comment: protocol won't help you with this, because you still need reimplement it's methods every time. If all your `pushViewController` calls are exactly the same then you can extend `UIViewController`, as @koropok suggested.