# how to send data between view controllers without using segue in IOS 9

Tags: ios

I displayed all phones contacts and I want to send selected contacts to another view controller. I took the selected data into array. There is no segue between two view controllers. I want to send data with out using segue.

Comment: Are you moving to that controller after selection? If yes, then which technique are you using to move?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929592/how-to-push-and-present-to-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-without-segue-in-io

Comment: " to another view controller" And how are they linked? What's the order of navigation? Childs? What's your ViewController architecture in your app? How do you present the second one?

Comment: I want to navigate from default contact view controller to another view controller. I  want to use storyboard id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate the destination view controller using `storyboard` instance and pass the data further :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestViewController") as! TestViewController
controller.variableX = self.variableX
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: variablex means

Comment: It can be any variable like String, object, collection, whatever you want to set.

Comment: can I set array to it

Comment: Of course. Anything you want to set, you can set.

Comment: In next view controller I have to mention variables?

Comment: @LahariAreti Obviously, just create a property of that type which you are going to pass (in your case create an blank array) in your destination (ViewController the your are presenting or pushing) and then pass you selected value to it. Then, you can easily access your passed details in destination viewController.

Comment: thank you.  I will try and let you know

Comment: @LahariAreti : Any update ?

Comment: I am getting this error Warning: Attempt to present <Spliting.DisplayViewController: 0x7fd9a1c1e170> on <Spliting.ViewController: 0x7fd9a1c0ad10> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: it doesn't display data into another view controller.but it navigate into another controller but didn't display the array of data..

Comment: @LahariAreti : Can you place a breakpoint in the above code and check if your first viewController array has some value. And then place a breakpoint in viewDidLoad of second viewController and see what is the value of the array.

Comment: the first view controller array have values that is selected contacts names.  what is break point

Comment: @LahariAreti : You know how to debug the code. Don't you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158505/discussion-between-lahari-areti-and-nitish).