# Switching from one View Controller to another without user interaction

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out how I can make a code which will make one View Controller go to the other without having to press a button to get to the second one.

Pretty much dong the same thing LaunchScreen.storyboard goes to Main.storyboard without having to press a button, it just does automatically. I am new to coding and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can push or present another view controller without any action. You just need to call the push or present code where you want to trigger it.

Ex:
If you want it to be triggered on timer function, add your push or present code there.

```
//I added this code in first viewController's viewDidAppear, so your second controller will be called after 10 seconds.
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //If you are using Storyboard
    //10.0 seconds
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {

        //If your first viewController is in Navigation stack
        if let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerID") as? SecondViewController {

            if let navigator = self.navigationController {

                navigator.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
            }
        }

        //If your first viewController is NOT in Navigation stack
        if let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewControllerID") as? SecondViewController {

            self.present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
 }
```

Refer this post:[How to push and present to UIViewController programmatically without segue in iOS Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929592/how-to-push-and-present-to-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-without-segue-in-io#)

Comment: How would the code be presented in an example and where would I be putting the code? In the 1st ViewController or the Second one?

Comment: You should add your code in first controller, if you are presenting or pushing second controller. Actually when/where you want to go to second controller?

Comment: I just want it to go to the second one that all, to just display the contents on the second view controller

Comment: Okay, but when you want to go to second controller?

Comment: After 10 seconds

Comment: How would i put that into the code on the first view controller for example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you actually want to show the view controller.

If you are trying to replicate a launch screen, then you probably don't want the next VC to be pushed onto the stack.

I'd imagine the best option for the information you've given would be to change the rootViewController after a short delay. Something like this should do:

```
let delayInSeconds = 5.0

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSeconds) { in

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let vc = ViewController()
    appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Comment: Where would I post this code in the AppDelegate or the first view controller that I am using?

Comment: in the first vc that you are using