# Problem with transition between scenes programatically

Tags: ios, swift, segue

My problem is that I can't find the correct code to transition between two scenes in IOS programatically. I have tried a few example codes, but none of them work as expected.

```
let vc storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "savedMode") as! SavedModeViewController
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This code goes to the new scene, but the back button doesn't appear in the left side of the navigation bar, and transition between scenes is wrong; instead of left to right animation, there is bottom to top animation.

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "savedMode") as! SavedModeViewController
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is the second code I have tried. The problem is that with this code, the navigation bar doesn't show at all in the second scene.

I have tried another way, but instead of second scene, the screen just turned black.

Comment: See [How to push and present to UIViewController programmatically without segue in iOS Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929592/how-to-push-and-present-to-uiviewcontroller-programmatically-without-segue-in-io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `present` will present the new view controller modally over the current view controller.

What you want is to push the new view controller onto the existing UINavigationController with [`pushViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller) .

```
if let savedVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "savedMode") as? SavedModeViewController, 
   let navigationController = self.navigationController {

    navigationController.pushViewController(savedVC, animated: true)

} else {

    // TODO: Handle unexpected nil occurrences
    print("Error loading SavedModeViewController")

}
```